# How to Automatically Produce Separated Words Using the Mathcal or Pazocal Fonts

Tags: xetex, pdftex, mathcal

Consider the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{calrsfs}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\pazocal}{OMS}{zplm}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet\pazocal{bold}{OMS}{zplm}{bx}{n}

\begin{document}
\Huge
\vskip 15pt
$\boldsymbol{\pazocal{EACH DAY}}$ \\
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

Even though "EACH DAY" was entered as text in the code, the two words are not separated. I gather that this is because `pazocal` is some kind of a math mode font.

To automatically separate the words, I have tried using `\text` in conjunction with `\pazocal`, but when I do, the font disappears (though the two words become separated).

I know that I can force a separation by adding horizontal space between the two words; but I would like to be able to do this automatically to accommodate, say, multiple words.

QUESTION: How may I use the `\pazocal` font and `boldsymbol` so that the individual words that are   typed within the braces of `pazocal{}` produce separated words with the desired font?

Thank you.

Comment: I added a version for math mode, but I'm not sure what the purpose of this would be.

Comment: @egreg Thank you for your answer and for your update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the font for text, you have to specify an interword space, because the relevant parameter in OMS encoded fonts is zero (for TeXnical reasons).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\newcommand{\textpazocal}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\spaceskip}{0.5em plus 0.2em minus 0.1em}%
  \usefont{OMS}{zplm}{bx}{n}#1%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\textpazocal{EACH DAY}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The final output is really ugly, isn't it?

If you insist for math mode…

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\pazocalalphabet}{OMS}{zplm}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet\pazocalalphabet{bold}{OMS}{zplm}{bx}{n}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\pazocal}{m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { ~ } { #1 }
  \pazocalalphabet{\seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \ }}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\pazocal{EACH DAY}$

$\boldsymbol{\pazocal{EACH DAY}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may want to substitute `{ \ }` with `{\mspace{12mu plus 4mu minus 2mu}}` to get

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\pazocalalphabet}{OMS}{zplm}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet\pazocalalphabet{bold}{OMS}{zplm}{bx}{n}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\pazocal}{m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { ~ } { #1 }
  \pazocalalphabet{\seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {\mspace{12mu plus 4mu minus 2mu}}}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\pazocal{EACH DAY}$

$\boldsymbol{\pazocal{EACH DAY}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Adjust the spacing to suit your taste.