# Strange Output When Color Shadowing Using the Pazocal Font

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, shadows, mathpazo, mathcal

This question is an extension of [How to Automatically Produce Separated Words Using the Mathcal or Pazocal Fonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/619908/how-to-automatically-produce-separated-words-using-the-mathcal-or-pazocal-fontsin) which egreg provides some answers.

Consider the following code which uses the `pazocal` font:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\newcommand{\textpazocal}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\spaceskip}{0.5em plus 0.2em minus 0.1em}%
  \usefont{OMS}{zplm}{bx}{n}#1%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\Huge
\textpazocal{EACH DAY}
\end{document}
```

which gives the output

[image]

Now, I would like to fancy it up a little by adding some color shadowing; however, the output of the following code (which works nicely for other fonts such as `bsifamily`) is not what one would expect with pazocal:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\textpazocal}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\spaceskip}{0.5em plus 0.2em minus 0.1em}%
  \usefont{OMS}{zplm}{bx}{n}#1%
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand\titleshading[3]{
    \newcommand\xoffset{0.3}
    \newcommand\yoffset{-0.25}
    % Blur
    \foreach \x in {-0.1,0.1} {
        \foreach \y in {-0.1,0.1} {         
            \node[blue!65!white] at (#1em+\xoffset em+\x em,#2em+\yoffset em+\y em) {
                \scalebox{2.5}{\Huge\textpazocal{#3}} 
            };
        }
    }

    % Main Shadow
    \node[blue!40!white] at (#1em+0.3em,#2em-0.2em) {
        \scalebox{2.5}{\Huge\textpazocal{#3}} 
    };
    \node[red] at (#1em,#2em) {% <-- here put the color you like 
        \scalebox{2.5}{\Huge\textpazocal{#3}} 
    };
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]   
    \titleshading{15}{0}{Each Day}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

If I run adjust the code for, say, the `bsifamily` font, the output looks like this---

[image]

QUESTION: What is the cause of the strange output with the pazocal font, and how may I fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried without fancy colors? Already `\textpazocal{a}` will fail because only the uppercase calligraphic letters are available.

Comment: @egreg Many thanks. I didn't know that about the uppercase letters. And alas, the colors are desired for the project I'm working on.

Comment: @egreg Would you know if color shadowing is possible with this font?

Comment: You got it, didn't you? There is *no* lowercase letter available, that's the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In your first example you used only uppercase letters. In your real code you are using lowercase letters. `OMS` is a math encoding and it has math symbols at these positions. Try to find a font which supports T1 or OT1 or another text font encoding.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\newcommand{\textpazocal}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\spaceskip}{0.5em plus 0.2em minus 0.1em}%
  \usefont{OMS}{zplm}{bx}{n}#1%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\Huge
\textpazocal{EACH DAY} \\
\textpazocal{Each Day}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As egreg pointed out, I have learned that this font only is applicable to uppercase letters. I noticed in your code that the colorized shadowing commands  are removed? Is such impossible, to the best of your knowledge, with this font?

Comment: Naturally you can color the font, your own screenshot in the question shows it. But your problem is not the color but the missing a.